# Matlab how to remove the weekend from the chart

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a line chart that the x-axis is datetime. But there is a weekend gap in the chart. I wonder how can I remove the gaps of the weekends.

---

[image]

```matlab
figure
plot(data.DateTime(1:833),data.diff(1:833),'b');
hold on
plot(data.DateTime(834:970),data.diff(834:970),'r');
hold on
plot(data.DateTime(971:1546),data.diff(971:1546),'b');
hold off
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the tick labels?  If you were labeling every day, ok, but with gaps in the labels having days spliced out is going to be incredibly confusing.

Comment: Besides the question of how to label the axes it's unclear why this would be a good idea for plotting data derived from the GBP/EUR exchange, which trades 24/7. It's unlikely the passage of time affecting this data continues where it left off after a weekend so removing the gaps is likely to be confusing if not misleading

Comment: How is your data sampled? You could just plot `diff` against its index, then label tick marks with appropriate dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `weekday` to filter your date to only include values for days of the week that aren't 6 or 7 (Saturday or Sunday)

```
days = datetime(2021,5,0:31);
days_weekdays_only = days(and(weekday(days)~=1,weekday(days)~=7));
```

This will filter the days data to only contain dates that are Mon-Fri.

Then plot this filtered data.

Edit: You can plot the values against an index of the filtered data and then change the x-axis labels to match the datetime string. This way it will skip the weekends but the x-axis will still show the date time.

```
days = datetime(2021,5,0:31);
weekdays = days(and(weekday(days)~=1,weekday(days)~=7));
data = randi(5,length(days),1);
data_weekdays = data(and(weekday(days)~=1,weekday(days)~=7));
idx = 1:length(weekdays);
plot(idx,data_weekdays)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',datestr(weekdays));
```

Comment: OP doesn't have data for the weekends. This is why the plot has gaps there. OP wants to remove the gaps in the plot.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Got it! I've modified the answer.